# How to get Camelot to read an a pdf file already opened as 'rb'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, python-camelot

Is there a way to use camelot to read an already opened pdf as 'rb' instead of using the camelot.read_pdf which takes a path as an argument?

Comment: You can open the same file in read mode more than once at the same time. They will be completely independent and reads of one will not affect the current read position of the other and vice versa.

Comment: I am getting the user to upload the pdf on a django webapp. And when I get the pdf, it is in the form of a io.bytesio object, which acts like a file opened in rb more. So I cannot open the file and have to work with the rb only.

Comment: Save the `BytesIO` as a temp file and open that in the other mode.

Comment: As you can read here (https://github.com/atlanhq/camelot/pull/376), the ability to read file object was implemented but never merged to master project.

Comment: pathlib.Path('file').write_bytes(io.BytesIO(b'data').getbuffer())    and then deleting the file is the only way i found it to work. Thank you for your help!